# Polynomial vertex coloring algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, coloring, np-complete

Assume that we have an polynomial algorithm $C(G, k)$ such that it defines if it is possible or not to make vertex coloring of graph $G$ in $k$ colors. 
Prove that there is an polynomial algorithm $D(G, k)$ such that it returns a vertex coloring of graph $G$ in $k$ colors. In the case it's not possible the algorithm returns that 'it is not possible'.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @zarathustra I have this task in homework and I have no idea at all.

Comment: To the people voting to close: I believe this question should not be closed. The OP does not show a partial solution, but for this problem either you get the idea or you don't. There is no algebraic manipulation or substitution that could get you closer to a solution, making this different than a question "Solve this equation" where the OP shows no effort.

Comment: To the OP: You are welcome to comment on my answer. Your question is getting voted to be closed, but I think it's worth keeping it on the site. So as to not be deleted automatically, please consider either upvoting and accepting my answer (if it helped you of course, otherwise you can comment what was wrong).

Comment: @zarathustra thank you very much. To be honest I haven't understood your solution yet but I also haven't tried hard. I mean this is the most difficult task of a home assignment and this topic was created in advanced. I will understand this solution probably today and if it is something missed in my head and guys around don't understand it either it will be a question asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G,k$ be the input of $D$. Let $\star_1,\dots,\star_k$ be new vertices, and let $V'$ be the set $V(G) \cup \{\star_1,\dots,\star_k\}$. For a graph $H$ on $V'$, a vertex $v\in V(G)$ and $k'\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, define $H_{+(v,k')}$ to be the graph whose vertices are $V'$, that contains all the edges of $H$ and edges $\{v,\star_i\}$ for every $i\neq k'$.

The algorithm works as follows: at any step, we keep a graph H on $V'$ such that for every $v\in V$, either $v$ is not connected to any $\star_i$ or $v$ is connected to all $\star_i$'s except one. Initially, the graph is $G$ to which we add $\{\star_1,\dots,\star_k\}$ as an isolated clique. Then we do the following:

- pick a vertex $v$ of $H$ that is not connected to any $\star_i$. If no such vertex exists, for each vertex of $V$ there is a unique $i$ such that $\{v,\star_i\}$ is not an edge of $H$. This $i$ gives you a colour for each vertex, which is a colouring of the graph.
- for every $k'\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, build the graph $H_{+(v,k')}$. Use $C$ to test if $H_{+(v,k')}$ is colourable. If it is, replace $H$ by $H_{+(v,k')}$. Otherwise try another $k'$. If for every $k'\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, the algorithm $C$ returns that $H_{+(v,k')}$ is not colourable, then return "not possible".

It is clear that the running time is polynomial, if $C$ runs in polynomial time.

The idea of the algorithm is that you check for an arbitrary vertex $v$  and an integer $k'$ whether there exists a colouring of $G$ that assigns the colour $k'$ to $v$. Of course, $G$ is $k$-colourable iff for at least one $k'$ this is the case and the resulting partially coloured graph is colourable. So you just continue imposing more and more constraints until you found a proper colouring of $G$. The new vertices $\star_1,\dots,\star_k$ form a gadget that allows to force $C$ to only consider colouring with some colours imposed.